# Removing following jQuery click function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, validation, forms, click

I am trying to add form validation to a custom post type in Wordpress with Jquery. Everything is working fine, except that there is a built in click event attached to the submit button that adds a class to make the button look disabled and also show the loading gif.

Now the form doesn't actually submit, but it looks like it does to a user, and this is confusing to a client. I tried adding removeClass to my validation script, but the built in script fires after mine and so I can't seem to do anything to affect it.

Is there a way of stopping this click event firing when the form is returned false, preferably without trying to find it in the Wordpress files (as this will not be worth it I feel)

Thanks

Update:

The part of the script (in autosave.js) that is adding the class is here

```
b('input[type="submit"], a.submitdelete', "#submitpost").click(function () {
        blockSave = true;
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        b(":button, :submit", "#submitpost").each(function () {
            var c = b(this);
            if (c.hasClass("button-primary")) {
                c.addClass("button-primary-disabled")
            } else {
                c.addClass("button-disabled")
            }
        });
        if (b(this).attr("id") == "publish") {
            b("#ajax-loading").css("visibility", "visible")
        } else {
            b("#draft-ajax-loading").css("visibility", "visible")
        }
    });
```

This is a bit too in depth for me, I'm not that adept at javascript. I'm not expecting anyone to get the wordpress files out, but can anyone immediately tell me what is happen at a glance? I'm thinking of just removing the addClass function as a cheap and tacky workaround (which I'll have to update every version), but I would of course prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the click handler on the objects, not just the class.

```
$('.button').removeClass('submit').unbind("click");
```

See this post [How to use .removeClass() to disable jquery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338723/how-to-use-removeclass-to-disable-jquery-function)

Comment: I just tried that and it still added the class, and also the subsequent click of the button got past the validation and submitted the form incorrectly

Comment: Hmmm.... its possible that the click is being delegated from an outer element. If thats the case then you'll probably have to dig through the wp files to finde where that event is being fired from.

Comment: I've found the part of the script that adds the class, but I'm not at all certain which bit I should edit

Comment: I'm thinking set a variable if the validation fails, then add that to the if statement I posted above, so if it is true, it will not add the class. However, how do I pass that variable to from one script to the next? It tells me it is undefined when it loads the wordpress scripts

Comment: I decided instead to just add the addClass to the validation script on success, and remove it from the wordpress files. Does mean I will have to update it on each version, but oh well.